# Are property values in CSS case-sensitive?

Tags: html, css, properties, case-sensitive

I have observed that some CSS properties, like `font-family` declared with quotation marks, perhaps are case-sensitive, but all other are not... But **how web-browsers and "HTML renderers" MUST interpret?** Is the same in any CSS context (XML, SVG, etc.) and all other applications? **What the standards say about?**

Example: *Adobe InDesign* exported both, `font-family:'Optima Bold'` and `font-family:'optima bold'`. Can I "normalize to lower case" (ex. to merge similar classes)?

### NOTES

References are incomplete and in conflict:

- [sitepoint.com/font-family](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-family) say "Note that font family names may be case sensitive on some operating systems"... It is valid for XHTML, it is updated with HTML5? `font-family`  is really the unique case-sensitive value?
- [Is it necessary to use lowercase for every Element and attribute , properties in css and xhtml ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115157/is-it-necessary-to-use-lowercase-for-every-element-and-attribute-properties-in) say indirectly "... use lowercase for every properties...", and answers not negate it.

---

Comparing with  [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533957), **the point here**, perhaps, can be translated to some (personal) objective considerations:

1. There are a (objective!) normative (W3C spec of CSS2, CSS3, XHTML1, or HTML5) source for this answer?
2. "Standard `font-family` unique names" can not be case-sensitive (otherwise cease to be standard)... So, the only justifiable (by sensible arguments) properties to be case-sensitive are:

   2.1. `X` values at `url(X)`, see `background`, etc. properties;

   2.2. `content` values, [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp);

   2.3. ... **more ??** ...

Comment: Those references are *not* in conflict since they refer to different elements.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question, perhaps I only need better references... The point is that there are no evident W3C assertion about it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(updating @ÁlvaroG.Vicario answer and comments, and [complementing this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533957/287948)... This is a Wiki, **please edit to enhance**)

Example: for CSS3 (and HTML5) there are new explicit rules, as "`font-face` property must be case-insensitive".[2]

---

### Context

W3C interoperating standards, mainly XML, HTML, CSV and CSS.

## CSS general rules

**CSS2** (a W3C standard of 2008) fixed basic conventions about "Characters and case", and **CSS3** (a W3C standard for 2015) added something more.

1. By default **"all CSS syntax is case-insensitive (...)"** [1]
2. **There are exceptions**, "(...) except for parts that are not under the control of CSS"[1]

2.1. element names are case-sensitive in HTML5 (?) and XML, but  case-insensitive in HTML4.

2.2. identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) are case-sensitive.  HTML attributes `id` and `class`, of font names, and of URIs lies outside the scope of the CSS specification.

3. ....
4. The

## Case matrix

Exceptions and specific (explicited in a reference) rules. "YES" indicate that value *is* case-sensitive.

**Property values:**

```
 CSS property      | Case-sens. | Reference and notes
 ------------------|------------|--------------------
 %colorVals        | NO         | [3]
 font-family       | NO         | [2]
 %url              | YES        | ...
 content           | YES        | ...
 ----------------------------------------------------
 %colorVals = color, background, etc.
 %url = background-image, etc. that use `url()`, see [7] and notes.
```

**Selector values:**

```
 CSS selector      | Case-sens. | Reference and notes
 ------------------|------------|--------------------
 id                | YES        |...
 element           | YES/NO     | ... YES for XML...
 class name        | YES        | [5]
 (`~ i` operator)  | NO         | [6]
 ----------------------------------------------------
 YES/NO = depends on the document language (see ref. and notes).
```

REFERENCES:

[1] [W3C/**CSS2**/syndata, sec. 4.1.3 Characters and case](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters).

[2] [W3C/**CSS3-fonts**, sec. 5.1 Case sensitivity of font family names](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family-casing)

[3] [W3C/**CSS3-color**, sec. 4.1. Basic color keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4)

[4] [W3C/**CSS3-values**, sec. 3.1. Pre-defined Keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#keywords)

[5] [W3C/**Selectors**, sec. 3. Case sensitivity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#casesens)

[6] [W3C/**Selectors4**, sec. 6.3. Case-sensitivity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case)

[7] [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and [URL syntax illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) at Wikipedia.

---

## Quotations and notes

- Typical URLs starts with [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name), that is case insensitive, but after it (*path*, *query* or *fragment* syntatical components), is case sensitive. See [7].
- *"User agents must match these names case insensitively"*. [2]

Comment: Few more case-insensitive items: CSS3 color names - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css2-system; pre-defined keywords - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#keywords

Comment: `background-image: url("adDressToImagE...")` is not case sensitive. (at less in chrome).

Comment: Hi @JuanmaMenendez, please edit, it is a Wiki! But see the problem, an URL value have its proper syntax, the first part, the domain, is case insesitive, but the remain is not (!). I edited to avoid confusion (and corrected table error).

Comment: @PeterKrauss you are right. According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html)

_"There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive"_

Comment: Hi @JuanmaMenendez, not need to comment,  I agree and the table in the text also agree, *" 'YES' indicate that value is case-sensitive"* (see note and ref [7]).

Answer (score 8):

The spec for [CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters) says:

> CSS syntax is **case-insensitive within the ASCII range** (i.e., [a-z] and
>   [A-Z] are equivalent), **except for parts that are not under the control
>   of CSS**. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of the HTML
>   attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies outside
>   the scope of this specification. Note in particular that element names
>   are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in XML.

... which makes quite sense: CSS itself accepts both `background-image` and `BACKGROUND-IMAGE` but it has no way to know whether your web server considers `LOGO.PNG` and `logo.png` as identical or different resources.

*(I've been unable to find the equivalent document for CSS3)*

Comment: Yes, your answer is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12533957  that not say something about *property values*... Have a occasional mention of "font names", but **where (?)** assertions about "*OK, font-variant, font-weight, text-decoration, text-transform, etc. **are case insensitive properties***". Yes, URL values (that contains something like `logo.png` are the unique, *the only justifiable by sensible arguments*)

Comment: Yours is a generalisation of the question you link. The answer is the same. Not sure if you have further questions... :-?

Comment: @PeterKrauss Er... Are you asking for reference about case sensitiveness in every single language and technology that can make use of CSS values at some point? That's a daunting task. Anyone can invent a vendor-prefixed attribute that performs a task. I can even invent my own language and let it use CSS for styling.

Comment: Sorry, the question is constrained by *W3C standards* (family of CSS-compatible and uptodate standards like HTML4, XHTML1, etc.). I can edit also about it, or add a "HTML" tag to the question.

Comment: [beware of the ol tag](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2101)